# Memcached 502 error when running siege (load testing)

Tags: linux, joomla, nginx, memcached

I am kind of new to server setups. I installed Nginx + NGX Pagespeed + PHP FPM + APC + MemCached on Ubuntu 12.04 and topped all of this with Joomla 3.1

All works well except when I try to run siege for load testing. When I use the -b parameter with siege (benchmarking), I start getting a 502 error immediately. Even if I bring the concurrent connections down to 2, I still get the error.

The site goes down and even in a browser, I get a 502 error. With some research, I think the issue is with the persistent connections in Memcached however I have no clue on how and where to tweak the configuration. In fact, I do not know how to proceed :-(

When I run siege, without the -b switch, and even with 50 users - all works fine.

Will appreciate some guidance preferably if you can point me to some links / tutorials.

Thanks and regards,
Mangesh

Comment: I had posted the same question in my VPS provider's forum, and I got an update saying I should add some swap. Checked and found out that there was no swap. Added it.

Comment: Post adding swap, it seems now siege reports a different error: siege aborted due to excessive socket failure. Did some research and found a similar question here on stack overflow. However the answer provided there is something on the lines of running sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.portrange.hifirst - When I do that, I get the following error: error: "net.inet.ip.portrange.hifirst" is an unknown key

Comment: Just in case someone would like to refer to the article I referred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463279/siege-aborted-due-to-excessive-socket-failure

Comment: My apologies. Issues resolved. The issue was with the unix socket that PHP FPM was listening on. Changed it to TCP.